# Remove the time in Datagridview and when exported to PDF

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2017-express

Please help me guys!
I want the time in Date_Purchased(date) to be removed in datagridview. Because whenever I exported the datagrid in PDF, it has the date and time in it. I only want the date and remove the time especially when exported to PDf.

Here's the sample piece of code.

```
     Public Sub NewInventory()
        Dim NI as SqlCommand =con.CreateCommand
        NI.CommandText = "Insert into Items_table(Room_ID, PC_Number, Item_Name, Date_Purhased) VALUES (@Room_ID,@PC_Number, @Item_Name, @Date_Purchased);"

        NI.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Room_ID", Room_ID)
        NI.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PC_Number", PC_Number)
        NI.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item_Name", Item_Name)
        NI.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_Purchased", DatePurchasedDTP.Value)

        NI.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("New item created.")
    End Sub

//for DataGridView

     Public Sub GetRoomItems(RoomID As String)
          Dim getItems As String = "Select Item_ID, PC_Number, 
      Item_Name, Date_Purchased WHERE Room_ID=" + RoomID
          Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(getItems, connection)

          Dim table As New DataTable()
          adapter.Fill(table)
          InventoryDataGrid.DataSource = table
     End Sub

//For exporting to pdf

     Private Sub ExportButton_Click(sender As Object, e As  EventArgs) Handles ExportButton.Click
          connection.Close()
          connection.Open()

          Dim pdfTable As New PdfPTable(ReportDataGridView.ColumnCount)
          pdfTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 1
          pdfTable.WidthPercentage = 100
          pdfTable.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element. ALIGN_CENTER

          Dim ptable As New  Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 11, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)

     For Each column As DataGridViewColumn in ReportDataGridView.Columns
          Dim cell as new PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk(column.HeaderText, ptable)))
          cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
          cell.FixedHeight = 30
          pdfTable.AddCell(cell)

     Next

     For Each row as DataGridViewRow In ReportDataGridView.Rows
          For each cell as DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
          pdfTable.AddCell(cell.Value.ToString)
          Next
     Next

         Dim folderpath As String = "C:\PDFs\"
         If Not Directory.Exists(folderpath) Then
              Directory.CreateDirectory(folderpath)
         End If

     Using sfd as New SaveFileDialog()
         sfd.ShowDialog()
         sfd.OverWritePrompt = True
         sfd.Title =" Save As"
         sfd.AddExtension = True
         sfd.DefaultExt = ".pdf"

          Using stream As New FileStream(sfd.FileName & ".pdf", 
FileMode.Create)
          Dim pdfdoc As New Document (PageSize.LETTER, 36.0F, 36.0F,36.0F,36.0F)
          PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfdoc.stream)
          pdfdoc.Open()
          pdfdoc.Add(pdfTable)
          pdfdoc.Close()
          stream.Close()
          If File.Exists("path") Then
               File.AppendAllText("path", "contents")
     End If
     pdfdoc.Close()
     stream.Close()
          End Using

     End Using
     End Sub
```

If you would ask me what's the data type of Date_Purchased, it is date. I used date not datetime. And still confused why the time is still in pdf whenever I exported it.

Please help me! Thank you so much

Comment: I don't see any code here which relates to your DataGridView or exporting to PDF?

Comment: Hi. I've already edited my code. Please take a look at it. I already included the code which relates to my DataGridView and exporting to PDF. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In .NET a `Date` still has a time component, it's just set to midnight (e.g. 12:00:00). You can read about this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=netframework-4.8

> A new object with the same date as this instance, and the time value
>   set to 00:00:00 midnight (00:00:00).

If you want to display a Date as a string with only the date, you can use `Date.ToString()` and specify a format which omits the time such as `Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`. Alternatively you can use `Date.ToShortDateString()` which does this but uses the current culture short date string format.

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.toshortdatestring?view=netframework-4.8

In your code you are doing this loop:

```vb
For Each row as DataGridViewRow In ReportDataGridView.Rows
    For each cell as DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
        pdfTable.AddCell(cell.Value.ToString)
    Next
Next
```

If you change this to use the underlying `DataTable` instead of the `DataGridView` itself you can use the `DataColumn.DataType` to check when you're using a date:

```vb
For Each row as DataRow In DataTable.Rows
    For Each item In row.ItemArray
        If item.GetType Is GetType("System.DateTime") Then
            pdfTable.AddCell(item.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
        Else
            pdfTable.AddCell(item.Value.ToString)
        End If
    Next
Next
```

I'm a bit rusty on the specifc syntax but you should be able to work it out from there.

Comment: There's an error in Datatable.Rows which says "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference"

Comment: It's not working. It doesn't get the items in DatagridView when I used your code and when I exported it to PDF.

Comment: You need to replace that pseudo-code with your own code. `DataTable.Rows` needs to be `NameOfYourDataTable.Rows`.